# Remove focus on escape at navbar-form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a `navbar-form` from the `bootstrap` framework. If the form gains focus, it's not possible to remove focus by pressing the `ESCAPE` key, which is a bit annoying.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxv4kvfc/) showing this effect. Is there a way to remove the focus, if the user presses the escape key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your fiddle, just add the following:

```
$('#search-field').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { $('#search-field').blur(); }
});
```

Note: you must use "keyup" or "keydown" as your trigger because "keypress" may give you different results depending upon your browser ([example](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)).